# Order by count of column in laravel 5.5 using eloquent orm

Tags: laravel

I am trying to set order by clause on count of field inside of larvel model.
I am using mongodb with Eloquent.
Is it even possible?

Here is a quick snippet of the query I am trying to run:

```
$books = Books::where(function ($query) use ($params, $res) {
                    $query->where('labels', 'elemMatch', array(
              'genre' => $res->genre,
                            'outdated' => $res->false
                        ))
                        ->where('available', true)
                        ->where('isSelling', true);
                })
                    ->orderBy('reviews','desc')
                    ->paginate($params['limit']);
```

Reviews is an array in my database
Is it possible to order by the count of it?

Comment: Could you please show us a row of your DB to see how reviews are stored?

Comment: As it mongodb it is just an array of pointers nothing special

Answer (score 0):

you can try doing this

```
$books = Books::where(function ($query) use ($params, $res) {
                $query->where('labels', 'elemMatch', array(
          'genre' => $res->genre,
                        'outdated' => $res->false
                    ))
                    ->where('available', true)
                    ->where('isSelling', true);
            })
                ->orderBy('reviews','desc')
                ->get();

// sorting the books using sortBy or sortByDesc
$books = $books->sortByDesc(function($book){
              return count(json_decode($book->reviews)); // we return the count of the reviews here
          }

// get sorted ids of the books
$ids = $books->pluck('id')->toArray();

// we get the books paginated with the ids order 
$books = $books->whereIn('id',$ids)
               ->orderByRaw(\DB::raw("FIELD(id, $ids)"))
               ->paginate($params['limit']);
```